# Fold in and Fold out in modifier

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, modifier

I have a question about jetpack compose modifier.
I can't understand foldin and foldout, what are them and when I can use them?
Thank you

Comment: This may be what you are looking for
https://proandroiddev.com/deep-dive-into-modifiers-jetpack-compose-a2605da4b88a